# `chmod` is not changing permissions of a file in /media/username/New Volume

Tags: permissions

I am trying to debug my Android code using Android Studio on an Ubuntu machine, but Android Studio is stopping on `adb initialize`
with error

```
Cannot run program "/media/aghed/New Volume/all programs/sdk2/sdk2/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied
```

I have tried:

```
sudo chmod 777 adb
```

on `~/sdk2/platform-tools/`

but the permissions are still:

```
ls -l adb
-rw------- 1 aghed aghed 2357745 تشرين 27 14:54 adb
```

It is not changing???

by the way I am running Ubuntu alongside Windows, not sure if it is relevant...

Comment: It's relevant *if the* `adb` *directory is located on the Windows filesystem*

Comment: Given the `/media/aghed/New Volume/` path, it sure is relevant.